# How to load txt and sum hours?

Tags: python

How to return sum of hours from txt file?

txt content:

```
Willy,10,37,40,20,30
Georgy,30,30,29.5,5
Addi, 20,20,20
Lisy,16,16,20
```

Is it makeable such result without importing any library?
result:

```
Willy:137
Georgy:94.5
Addi:60
Lisy:52
```

## Update

I would like to be able to sum hours by name, ie: given the following data (note the two occurrences of `Willy`, I should achieve the same results as above:

```
Willy,10,37,20
Georgy,30,30,29.5,5
Addi, 20,20,20
Lisy,16,16,20
Willy,40,30
```

Comment: after opening txt I was tried to use `isdigit()` to work only with int but it was giving me sum of all numbers or simply error bcuz sometimes it was also considering string...

Comment: I'd also mention that importing a library (especially the stdlib) is not something you should work to avoid. Python has great "batteries included" and you should use them to your advantage when necessary.

Comment: @JonClements do u know is there any website which summarise countnent of most useful libraries? libraries are here, am i right? `C:\Python27\Lib` I have started learn python 1 week ago

Comment: I'm not aware of any such website, but the list of the stdlib can be found at http://docs.python.org/2/library/ - `collections` and `itertools` are very useful to know, but I'm somewhat hesitant to make recommendations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sums per line

Another slightly different version, without fancy imports or `map`.
Just `split`, `float` and a list comprehension.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        name,hours = l.split(',',1)
        print '%s:%s' % (name, sum([float(x) for x in hours.split(',')]))
```

Output with the data in the updated question:

```
Willy:67.0
Georgy:94.5
Addi:60.0
Lisy:52.0
Willy:70.0
```

### Sums per person

If that's not what you're looking for (you want to sum multiple lines with the same name), you could try the following dictionary based approach:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    d = {}
    for l in f:
        name,hours = l.split(',',1)
        if name in d:
            d[name] = d[name] +  int(sum([float(x) for x in hours.split(',')]))
        else:
            d[name] = int(sum([float(x) for x in hours.split(',')]))
for n in d:
    print '%s:%s' % (n, d[n])
```

As you will see, this combines the two lines for Willy:

```
Willy:137.0
Georgy:94.5
Addi:60.0
Lisy:52.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but it give me only result of first line, and when there is multiply line with same name than it doesn't count it

Comment: What's the output you get? And is your file called data.txt?

Comment: I'm getting such output: `Willy: 67.0`

Comment: @user1768615: Updated my answer so multiple lines with Willy will be combined

Comment: if there are 2x Willy with different numbers is there possibility that second one is ignored?
#edit
is it possible use `set()` to dont get multiply result?

Comment: Not in the second approach, they'll be summed together in the line `d[name] = d[name] +  sum([float(x) for x in hours.split(',')])`

Comment: with second code, I'm getting this error `d = defaultdict(int)
NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined`

Comment: My bad, I forgot the import line; `from collections import defaultdict
`.

Comment: is there any way to achieve such result without touching any library?

Comment: @user1768615: Yes, you could replace the defaultdict with a normal dictionary, which would eliminate the import. The code would become slightly clunkier though.

Comment: i have tried replace defaultdict with normal dictionary but it didnt work out ;< `d = {}`, I dont want look like an who want always more and more but this is going to be last thing =P sorry for making it long, how can i simply sum numbers without getting numbers with dot, not `45.5` right one `45` ?

Comment: Used `long()` in place of `float()`. trying to find out some tutorial in internet for this part but without results... `'%s:%s' % (n, d[n])`

Comment: @user1768615: Updated once more, now without defaultdict or any import, and with whole numbers. For the `%s` thing, see [**here**](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html).

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
>>> with open("data2.txt") as f: 
...     for line in f:           #traverse over each line
...         spl=line.split(",")  #split the line at ","
                             #so now spl[0] is the name and spl[1:] are the hours 
...         print "{0}:{1}".format(spl[0],sum(map(float,spl[1:])))

         #sum(map(float,spl[1:])) returns the sum of hours after converting them to floats
```

**output:**

```
Willy:137.0
Georgy:94.5
Addi:60.0
Lisy:52.0
```

**EDIT:** For your updated question:
using `OrderedDict()`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict as od
with open("data2.txt") as f:
    dic=od()
    for line in f:
        spl=line.split(",")
        name,summ=spl[0],sum(float(x) for x in spl[1:])
        dic.setdefault(spl[0],[]).append(summ)
    for x,y in dic.items():
        print"{0}:{1}".format(x,sum(y))
```

**output:**

```
Willy:137.0
Georgy:94.5
Addi:60.0
Lisy:52.0
```

Comment: If you do `"{0}:{1}".format(...)` your answer will be py2.6 compatible too.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, could u be so kind and explain me what is purphose of importing from library 1 code and renaming it?

Comment: @user1768615 nothing special I find `OrderedDict` long so I just used a small alias `od`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary could u explaind me what's meaning of `{0}:{1}`, please?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, using ur first code, is it possible somehow remove multiply name but get result at 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on that output, I'd use `str.split` and `sum` with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
with open('txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,data = line.split(',',1)
        print '{0}:{1}'.format(name,sum(ast.literal_eval(data)))
```

Here I split the string into 2 strings at the first comma, I then use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string on the right into a tuple of numbers.  You could also do

```
sum(float(x) for x in data.split(','))
```

instead of:

```
sum(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

but this will always give you a floating point result (even if all of the input numbers are integers) -- Although I bet the solution without `ast.literal_eval` would execute faster...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        print ':'.join((line[0], str(sum([float(e) for e in line[1:]]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of using a defaultdict to accumulate all hours for a given name, and then iterating over it to show the total number of hours. (You could of course sum on the go, and not build the list, but knowing the exact hours may come in useful later?)

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

name_hours = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        name, hours = row[0], row[1:]
        row[name].extend(map(int, hours))

print name_hours

for name, hours in name_hours.iteritems():
    print name, sum(hours)
```